# PHP Counting results from Access database

Tags: php, ms-access

This should be ease but I can’t find the answer.  I want the number of results to appear at the top of the page.

```
<?php
$db = realpath('C:\AccessBackEnds\Supplylist\SupplyEnd.accdb');
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$db",'','') or die
("Unable to connect to server");

$name = $_GET['ServiceLineItem'];

$info1 = "SELECT * FROM CiscoROS WHERE ServiceLineItem ='$name'";
$rs1=odbc_exec($conn,$info1);

echo odbc_num_rows($info1);

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs1))    {
echo "<dt>Company:  </dt><strong>" . $row["Company"] . "</strong>";
echo "<dt>Monitoring Status:  </dt><strong>" . $row["MonitoringStatus"] . "</strong>";
echo "<br>*******************************************************************";

}

odbc_close($conn)
?>
```

Comment: What is it doing now? Nothing? Printing an error? Printing the wrong number?

Answer (score 0):

`odbc_num_rows()` expects to be passed the resource returned by the `odbc_exec()` call. You are currently passing it a string (which happens to be the SQL statement). To get the number of rows returned you *could* try using...

`odbc_num_rows($rs1)`

...but not all ODBC drivers return the actual row count returned by a SELECT statement. Many drivers only return the actual rows affected for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements, and just return -1 for SELECT statements; the Microsoft Access Driver is one of those.

So instead, you could do `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM CiscoROS WHERE ...` first, or you could just loop through the rows first to count them, then loop through them again to print them out.

Also, please also note...

You are taking `$name` directly from `$_GET` and stuffing it into an SQL statement. That leaves you vulnerable to **SQL injection** attacks. You *really should* consider using parameterized queries. (Check out `odbc_prepare()` and `odbc_execute()`.)